# I created the ingress for Kubernetes dashboard but somehow the dashboard is not reachable?

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, kubernetes-dashboard

I'm trying to load Kubernetes-dashboard using ingress. Not able to connect to the domain name that I specified in the YAML file
Created the secret TLS and resolved the hostname as well.

```
 apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: dashboard-ingress
      namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
      annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    spec:
      tls:
      - hosts:
        - dashboardoverdose.com
        secretName: dashboard-secret-tls
      rules:
      - host: dashboardoverdose.com
        http:
          paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix  
            backend:
              service:
                name: kubernetes-dashboard
                port: 
                  number: 443
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is the ingress annotation issue, and sounds like the Kubernetes version is `>= 0.21.0`

```
  ## If you plan to use TLS backend with enableInsecureLogin set to false
  ## (default), you need to uncomment the below.
  ## If you use ingress-nginx < 0.21.0
  #   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
  ## if you use ingress-nginx >= 0.21.0
  #   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
```

[kubernetes-dashboard-ingress](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/aio/deploy/helm-chart/kubernetes-dashboard/values.yaml#L181)

so try this

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dashboard-ingress
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - dashboardoverdose.com
      secretName: dashboard-secret-tls
  rules:
  - host: dashboardoverdose.com
    http:
      paths:
        - pathType: Prefix
          path: "/"
          backend:
            service:
              name: kubernetes-dashboard
              port:
                number: 443
```